# Java LWJGL Changing a texture's alpha value

Tags: java, textures, lwjgl, alphablending

Can I use code in LWJGL to change a texture's alpha value? or render a texture with a certain alpha value without creating a couple images of the texture with different alpha values?

EDIT:

Figured it out, you change to color of the quad you are binding the texture to and just set the alpha level using:

```
glColor4f(1f,1f,1f,alphaValue);
```

Comment: In the future, if you find a solution go ahead and post it as an answer and then mark it as such. This makes it easier to find the solution when someone else has the same question.

Comment: Sorry but I have to wait 8 hours before I can answer my own question.

Comment: Do you need to wait to answer or to accept? And no need to apologize, it's just something to keep in mind to help others :)